# JavaScript Regex that matches everything starting with a specific pattern until there's not a whitespace or newline

Tags: javascript, regex

I was searching for a **JavaScript** 2015/ES5 and up regex that matches everything starting with a pattern until there's not a blank space or newline, but that does not take in the last space or newline

I'm not looking for a single pattern, but it has to be exchangeable for what you made.

Assuming that the starting text it's

```
protocol://EVERITING protocol://EVERITING2
protocol://%$&/()=
```

and the start pattern it's

`protocol:\/\/`

has to gives back in matches:

```
"protocol://EVERITIN"
"protocol://EVERITING2"
"protocol://%$&/()="
```

It's possible to make something like this?

Comment: Just use `\S+` after your pattern?

Comment: @Sebastian Simon Listen could you make an example over [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: `protocol:\/\/\S+`

Comment: Konrad please make a working example over [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/) with my pattern so anyone can see

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/0xMSZb/1

Comment: [https://regex101.com/r/0xMSZb/1](https://regex101.com/r/0xMSZb/1) Exactly what i need. TNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript (2015/ES5 and up), this should yield the result you're looking for:

```js
const input = `protocol://EVERITING protocol://EVERITING2
protocol://%$&/()= 
protocol://sdofihsofhia;sjf.ew/asjodfihapc80hem/ test
donotmatch
protocol:/s/alsodontmatch`

const matches = input.matchAll(/protocol:\/\/\S+/g)

for (const match of matches) {
  console.log(`Found ${match[0]} start=${match.index} end=${match.index + match[0].length}`);
}

// alternatively, in more condensed format:

console.log([...input.matchAll(/protocol:\/\/\S+/g)])
```